# java.lang.NullPointerException In Fragment when trying to use AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to display an alert dialog inside a Fragment (inside an error callback if that matters). Here's the error:

```
05-21 11:05:33.635  31869-31869/me.myapp.local E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:210)
            at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getSystemService(ContextThemeWrapper.java:75)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams.<init>(AlertController.java:673)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:280)
            at me.myapp.fragment.SectionFrag$1.failure(SectionFrag.java:179)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$2.run(CallbackRunnable.java:53)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here's the section of code:

```
@Override
public void failure(final RetrofitError error) {
Log.wtf(TAG, error);
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDB = new     AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), android.support.v7.appcompat.R.style.Base_Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert)
alertDB.setCancelable(false);
```

I'm using API 22 and v4 Fragments. The issue that has me boggled is I ***ONLY*** get this crash if using the system BACK button. If using my apps's up/back menu item that I display in my actionbar, this section of code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `getActivity()` is returning `null` meaning your fragment is no longer attached to an activity.

Comment: Would this be the case if the user presses the back button in the Fragment, vs pressing the back button in my actionbar? In both cases, my Fragment's onPause() is called.

Comment: You can add logging in the `onDetach()` method of your fragment to see when that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you're getting a `NullPointerException` because your application fragment can't define which Activity it belongs. You can try to define the context when the user presses the back button.

Therefore, if you're using AlertDialogs inside your Fragment, you should use a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) instead.

Comment: I added a bit more debug, and getActivity() returns null when the back button is pressed, but not when my application's back/up button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

are you try getContext() insteadof getACtivity() it work for me